# How to pass model in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass model from form to controler and show others models in the same view. How can I do this? My main problem is: how to send into testAcc actionresult, model CommentModel, and show text in `ViewData["Success"]` ?

Here is my code:

```
    @model XYZ.Models._ideaDetailsWrapper
    @using XYZ.Tools   
<article>
    <h2>@Model.idea.Tilte</h2>

<table><tr><td>
<p>
    Author: <b>@UserTools.getUser(Model.idea.AuthorID).UserName</b><br />
    Add date: @Model.idea.AddDate<br />
    Category: @IdeasTools.getCategoryName(Model.idea.CategoryID)<br />
</p></td>
</tr></table>

<p><b>Content:</b><br />
    @Model.idea.Content</p>

<br /><br />

// HERE - ADD comment

    @using (Html.BeginForm("testAcc", "Ideas", FormMethod.Post))
    { 
            <h4>Add comment:</h4>

            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.addComment.Content)
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.addComment.Content)<br />
        <input type="submit" value="SendEmails" />
    }

@ViewData["Success"]
```

wrapper:

```
public class _ideaDetailsWrapper 
{
    public Ideas idea { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IdeasComment> commentList { get; set; }
    public CommentModel addComment { get; set; }
}
```

Action method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult testAcc(CommentModel model)
    {

        CommentModel abs = model;

        ViewData["Success"] = "Working!";

        // ADD TO DATABASE, but model is null..
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Ideas");
    }
```

Comment: RedirectToAction asks the browser to redirect the request elsewhere, so the browser requests the new URL, this is a separate request, so it won't know anything about your model or ViewData from the first request.

Comment: but when I debug, variable `CommentModel model` in testAcc method is always null

Comment: Where? Not in the testAcc method (unless there are bits missing you're not showing us) and if it is in the view then that's because, as I said, it is a separate request from the browser and has no information about the previous request.

Comment: I tested it in this line `CommentModel abs = model;`. Without model (just passing one string from textbox) this methods works perfecly (testAcc). But for passing model - there are some troubles. I stop debuger before `RedirectToAction`..

Comment: Based on your code change: The model of your view and the model in the testAcc method do not match and it can't coerce one to the other (the properties have different names), so it doesn't know what to do and cannot match them up. If you look at the actual HTML produced you'll see that what ever is produced by EditorFor will be named something like "addCommant_Content", but the POST action is expecting something called "Content"

Comment: Can you check with Firebug or Chrome what is the form data sent back? Is the `Content` property enough to create a `CommentModel` instance?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a **Partial View**.

**Details.cshtml**

```
@model XYZ.Models._ideaDetailsWrapper
...
// HERE - ADD Comment
<div id="comment-form">
@Html.Partial("_CommentForm", Model.addComment)
</div>

@Model.message
// add validation javascript to this view
```

**_CommentForm.cshtml** (Partial View)

```
@model XYX.Models.CommentModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("testAcc", "Ideas", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
      @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <h4>Add comment:</h4>

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Content)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Content)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Content)<br />
    <input type="submit" value="SendEmails" />
}
```

The partial view is strongly typed and will submit the `CommentModel`

Action methods:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult testAcc(CommentModel model)
{
    string abs = model.Content;

    TempData["Message"] = "Working!";

    // ADD TO DATABASE
    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Ideas", new { id = model.Idea.Id });
}

[HttpGet]
[Autorize]
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var ideaModel = dbStore.GetIdea(id);  // however you do this

    var model = new _ideaDetailsWrapper {
        idea = ideaModel,
        addComment = new CommentModel(),
        message = TempData["Message"]
        ...
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Use `TempData` to pass the message through redirect. You'll check if `TempData["Message"]` exists in the `Details` action when you first load the page directly before you use it.

**Edit:** For Validation just add the validation javascript to the Details view and the `ValidationSummary` to the partial view.

**Edit 2:** This method breaks down with validation and error handling. For this to work it needs AJAX to replace the form div without reloading the entire page.

You need to intercept the normal form submission and handle it yourself using AJAX

```
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Ideas/testAcc",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("form").serialize()
    })
    .done(function(partialViewHtml) {
        $("#comment-form").html(partialViewHtml);
    });
});
```

Your action becomes

```
[HttpPost]
public ActioNResult testAcc(CommentModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ...
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Ideas", new { id = model.Idea.Id });
    }
    return PartialView("_CommentForm", model);
}
```

Comment: thanks ! now it works. But how to validate fields in model when `<input type="submit" value="SendEmails" />` is clicked? Messages from model, like this : `[Required]` etc?

Comment: Add the validation scripts to the `Details` view

Comment: `@Html.ValidationSummary()` - this one, yep? Still doesn't work. On input click, page is reloading without validation..

Comment: Hmm, not sure as I've usually done it this way with AJAX. Try adding a `HttpGet testAcc` that `return PartialView("_CommentModel", model)`. Then when you fail validation in `HttpPost` just `return View(model)`.

Comment: In `[HttpPost]` when I put `return View(model)` I get error `The view 'testAcc' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations`. But when I put `return View("_CommentForm",test);` - it works and validation runs properly, but it show only this partialview, without rest `Details` elements. Do you know why and how to resolve it? Regards !

Comment: It appears that validation is working but that's the validation javascript preventing form submission on the client-side. It would be more robust if you handled a post with invalid values on the sever-side as well. See the added AJAX example which should address the missing `Details` issue.