# How to bind value from UI to controller with complex model in c# mvc

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I'm new to .net. I have this model that has been a real trouble for me for days.

class **DetailedRecordModel**

```
public class DetailedRecordModel
    {
        public string RecordID { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public string InitDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public string DeliveryDate { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PurchaseDetail> detail{ get; set; }
}
```

class **PurchaseDetail**

```
public class PurchaseDetail
    {
        public string ProductID { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
        public string RecordID { get; set; }

    }
```

controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(DetailedRecordModel record)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
            return View(record);
             
            }
                return RedirectToAction("ViewRecords");
        }
```

html

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["sellistemp"])
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["sellistcust"])
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
 <tr>
       <td style="display:none" id="Index0" name="detail.Index" value="0"></td>
       <td>1</td>
       <td id="ProductID" name="detail[0].ProductID" value="sp00002">sp00002</td>
       <td id="Qty" name="detail[0].Qty" value="12123">12123</td>
       <td id="price" name="detail[0].price" value="2312">2312</td>
</tr>
<tr>
       <td style="display:none" id="Index1" name="detail.Index" value="1"></td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td id="ProductID" name="detail[1].ProductID" value="sp00003">sp00003</td>
       <td id="Qty" name="detail[1].Qty" value="2323">2323</td>
       <td id="price" name="detail[1].price" value="3223">3223</td>
</tr>
```

for RecordID, EmployeeID, CustomerID, InitDate and DeliveryDate  passing them to the controller is all fine, however I always get null for `<PurchaseDetail> detail`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the model to the view by using `View(myModel)` or `RedirectToAction("ViewRecords", record)`

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(DetailedRecordModel record)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ViewRecords", record);
         
        }
        return View(record);
    }

    public IActionResult ViewRecords(DetailedRecordModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
```

then in the View you can access the model like here [How to pass model in MVC view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126049/how-to-pass-model-in-mvc-view)

1. add the definition of your model at the top of `@model DetailedRecordModel;`
2. after you added the model you can access it everywhere in your file with `@Model` (in html) or `Model`

```html
    @model DetailedRecordModel;
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "ViewRecords";
    }

    <h1>ViewRecords</h1>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["sellistemp"])
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["sellistcust"])
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @foreach (var entry in Model.detail)
    {
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none" id="Index0" name="detail.Index" value="0"></td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td id="ProductID" name="@entry.ProductID" value="sp00002">sp00002</td>
            <td id="Qty" name="@entry.Qty" value="12123">12123</td>
            <td id="price" name="@entry.price" value="2312">2312</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: can you be more particular? Im not really getting it. The second code part doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Model.get returned null'. Now the site is inaccessible somehow.

Comment: could you post how your controller looked like before? If you just copied my two methods it would not work maybe you miss the [HttpGet] above the ViewRecords method

Comment: Well look below, I found the solution to this. It(something) automatically binds the value when I change ```<td id="price" name="detail[0].price" value="2312">2312</td>``` name to how the nested object was named.ex: ```wrongname[0].price``` to ```nestedname[0].price```. I actually used javascript to automatically generate ```<tr>```s, the code below is just demonstration. Thanks for trying to help anyway

Answer (score 0):

After 2 wretching days of desperation I know that in order to bind the values, I found the answer by declaring an object `DetailedRecordModel` inside model `PurchaseDetail` and I have to change the name of each `<input>` tag into `detail[index].somevariable`